# Convert Javascript Regex Result to String(?)

Tags: javascript, regex

I extracted a string inside a parenthesis using a simple RegExp expression. I'm trying to split the result to an array.

But I am getting a `"Cannot read property 'split' of null" ERROR`. Which is weird because `vrb1` returns `(a, b)`.

I already tried converting `vrb1` to string with `toString()` but It didn't work.

Could this error be because of RegExp match result? Your help is very much appreciated.

```
str = sample(a, b);

var regex = new RegExp("[\(]([^\)])+[\)]","g");
var vrb1 = str.match(regex);
var tmp = vrb1.split(",");
return tmp;
```

Comment: `match` can return null if no result is found.

Comment: But `vrb1` returns a value

Comment: *match* returns an array (or null if no match), not a string. Use `var vrb1 = str.match(regex) || []` so then you'll know *vrb1* is a (possibly empty) array.

Comment: Also note that when using the RegExp constructor, back slashes must also be quoted, so `new RegExp("[\\(]([^\\)])+[\\)]","g")` or use a literal: `/[\(]([^\)])+[\)]/g;`

Answer (score 3):

[`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) returns an array, not a string.

> **Return value**
>
> `array`
>
> An Array containing the entire match result and any parentheses-captured matched results, or null if there were no matches.

In your case you want something like:

```
if (vrb1 !== null) {
    var tmp = vrb1[0].split(',');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`match` will return **null** if no result is found.

You need simply check for null as well.

Replace

```
var tmp = vrb1.split(",");
```

with

```
var tmp = vrb1 || [];
```

This will return an empty array if no result is found.

**Edit**

Looks like you are further splitting the result by `comma`, then try

```
var tmp = vrb1 ? vrb1[0].split(",") : [];
```

or since there are multiple results (`g` in your regex)

```
var tmp = vrb1 ? vrb1.join(",").split(",") : [];
```

Comment: Half way there. *match* returns null or an array. Arrays don't have a split method.

Comment: @RobG thanks, i had missed out that OP is further splitting the results by comma.